# Issue querying a json value in laravel project

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I'm trying to fetch a record from MSSQL table based on field value which contains json data. Following is the sample column value for 'updated_value' column:

```
[[{"phone_number":"5555555555","phone_type":"H","inactive_date":null,"restrictions":["SU","F"],"start_time":null,"end_time":null}]]
```

My query is:

```
$existing = ContactChangeLogs::latest()
        ->where('updated_value->phone_number', '5555555555')
        ->first();
```

But `dd($existing)` gives `null` result.

Comment: the `updated_value` is an array of array so try to do `updated_value[0]->phone_number`

Comment: [SQL Server]Invalid column name 'updated_value[0]'. (SQL: select top 1 * from [contact_change_logs] where json_value([updated_value[0]]], '$."phone_number"') = 5555555555 order by [created_at] desc) - Getting this error @MAHAOUEGHLANI

Comment: @Zhorov
 Can you help me out writing the said raw query to my code?  ->whereRaw("WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM OPENJSON(updated_value) j1 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) j2 WHERE JSON_VALUE(j2.[value], '$.phone_number') = '5555555555'") I know this is wrong

Comment: @Geethu, I think it is something like this: `->whereRaw("EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM OPENJSON(updated_value) j1 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) j2 WHERE JSON_VALUE(j2.[value], '$.phone_number') = ?)", ['5555555555'])`.

Comment: @Zhorov Thank you It worked. Can you add this as a new comment. so I can accept this  as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach is to use `whereRaw()` method to build a raw `WHERE` clause for your query. The actual statement depends on the JSON structure and in your case you need two `OPENJSON()` calls to parse the nested JSON content:

```
->whereRaw(
   "EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM OPENJSON(updated_value) j1 
      CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) j2 
      WHERE JSON_VALUE(j2.[value], '$.phone_number') = ?
    )",
    ['5555555555']
)
```

As an additional note, if the JSON content has this fixed structure (two nested arrays, the first one containing a single JSON array and the second one with a single JSON object as item), you may simplify the statement:

```
->whereRaw(
   "JSON_VALUE(updated_value, '$[0][0].phone_number') = ?",
    ['5555555555']
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `JSON_VALUE` function to extract the 'phone_number' value from the JSON data

```
$existing = DB::select(
    "SELECT TOP 1 * 
       FROM contact_change_logs 
      WHERE JSON_VALUE(updated_value, '$[0].phone_number') = '5555555555'"
);
```

Comment: `LIMIT` is not a valid SQL Server keyword.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i just forgot that you are using MSSQL, check the updated query now.

Comment: @Amit Mohanty No results

Comment: @AmitMohanty, you need a different path (`'$[0][0].phone_number'`) to parse this JSON content.

Comment: @AmitMohanty Yup this is working as well. Please update your main comment. So i can upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereJsonContains()` instead of `where()`.

```
$existing = ContactChangeLogs::latest()
        ->whereJsonContains('updated_value->phone_number', '5555555555')
        ->first();
```

Comment: same null result @Mit Kathrotia